# boost thread while all thread not completed print something

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

need to know that

```
boost::thread_group tgroup;
```

loop 10 times

```
tgroup.create_thread( boost::bind( &c , 2, 2, ) )
```

<==

```
tgroup.join_all()
```

What can i do at the <== location above to continuously print the number of threads who have completed there jobs

Answer (score 1):

You can use an atomic counter: See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2245c0b708da6fa4)**

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

static boost::atomic_int running_count(20);

static void worker(boost::chrono::milliseconds effort) 
{ 
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(effort);
    --running_count;
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group tg;

    for (int i = 0, count = running_count; i < count; ++i) // count protects against data race!
        tg.create_thread(boost::bind(worker, boost::chrono::milliseconds(i*50)));

    while (running_count > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Monitoring threads: " << running_count << " running\n";
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }

    tg.join_all();
}
```

Example output:

```
Monitoring threads: 19 running
Monitoring threads: 17 running
Monitoring threads: 15 running
Monitoring threads: 13 running
Monitoring threads: 11 running
Monitoring threads: 9 running
Monitoring threads: 7 running
Monitoring threads: 5 running
Monitoring threads: 3 running
Monitoring threads: 1 running
```

Another way would be to use a semaphore

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to print thread id at the end of job "c":

```
void c()
{
//some code here
some_safe_print << boost::this_thread::get_id();
}
```

That way, when thread will finish, the last instruction would be to print it's id.